# HTML bootstrap separation line between divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am practicing with bootstrap and HTML. Please take a look at the picture where I've managed to build and display a return flight. Next thing that I would like to do in order to make it look nicer and more structured: introduce a separation line between flights (separate outgoing from return).

My problem is that I am not sure what to use in order to achieve such design feature in HTML using bootstrap. Should I introduce another `row` between flights and inject an image or just try to accomplish it by using `borders`?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

```
<div class="container well well-md searchResult">

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="departFlyRow">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div><b>06:20</b></div>
                            <div>LHR</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div>5h 30</div>
                            <div>direct</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div><b>12:50</b></div>
                            <div>SVO</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="returnFlyRow">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div><b>06:20</b></div>
                            <div>SVO</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div>5h 30</div>
                            <div>direct</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div><b>12:50</b></div>
                            <div>LHR</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 selectButtonColumn">
                    <div><b>&pound;100</b></div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Select</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Add a bottom border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<hr>` between your `returnFlyRow` div's.

Also add the `clearfix` class to the `returnFlyRow` divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/m9nn9tvj/1/

**I changed your `col-md-2` to `col-xs-2` to work better in jsfiddle.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following:
1.For the start flight, start the row with an icon of an airplane taking off, for the return flight, start the row with an icon of airplane descending.
2. Arrange start and return in columns.
3. Add a border between flights.

HTH.